# Can we install SSIS Services successfully on existing SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2

Tags: service, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Can we install SSIS Services successfully  on existing SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2? Please advice

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 have reached end of life several years ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: Agree with @marc_s.  SSIS is part of the 2008 R2 product, but there's a lot of reason to install the latest version of SQL if you're doing anything new.